# Unable to resize second background space

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I am just beginning with web coding now and I do apologize for any nonsense things I might come up with.

I am trying to modify a template of a website. This website is divided in two background pictures, one is for the top that goes a bit beyond the middle of the page, and the other one is supposed to be for the bottom of the page.

What I am trying to do is to make the top background picture come further down close to the bottom navigation bar, and than let the second background picture to seat on the bottom of the page where the bottom navigation bar is.

Here is the complete CSS http://pastebin.com/h2KdKtdq

The top background picture part is

```
.bg1 {background:url(../images/bg1.gif) center 0 repeat-x; min-height:100%;}
```

While the bottom background picture part

```
body { 
background:url(../images/bg.gif) 50% 0 repeat;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px; 
line-height:18px;
color:#978e83;
min-width:1003px;
}
```

What's strange is that whatever I do to the bottom picture part in the CSS wont take any effect, while if I touch the top picture part it will simply mess out the whole layout.

So far I haven't found any options to make the space of the bottom background part coming any further dow, and I am literally stuck into this.

Here's how the style looks now

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you're new to coding, I'm trying to simplify as much as possible. Forgive me if I've oversimplified.

I actually just wrote out a long explanation and then noticed the address bar is visible in your image - I checked the site and the top and bottom are actually both in bg1.gif. The body background image is just more of the same bottom color to cover past where the bottom of bg1.gif goes.

So there's a simple solution:

```
    .bg1{background-size: 100% 150%;}
```

Just change the second value and the size of the color blocks will shift. All it does is scale the background and since, in this case, the background is simple colors it shouldn't have much of a problem interpolating the image.

This is the easiest way to fix your immediate problem. Ideally, you'd code the whole background differently. I'll post another response below with how to do this.

---

EDIT: I just noticed that there is a small line between the colored areas and there is a barely perceptible texture to the color areas - regardless my above solution still works, with slight distortion. So long as you aren't stretching too much, you should be ok.

If you want to do this without any distortion, the easiest solution is to just edit the image and add more space on the top. Editing the image is a good idea anyway because the way the background is currently formatted uses a lot of overhead. The background is 1309px x 1228px but it could just be 10 px wide with repeat-x. That alone could reduce the file size from 851kb to ~10kb.

Comment: It worked thank you:) .. You saved me further more days of investigations.